# Fixed some grammar

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to see if a value from my data matches against an array of values to return true or false.

Here is what I have come up with so far...

```
acceptedGrades = ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3'];

this.state.isValidGrade = _.every(acceptedGrades, d => item.grade === value);
```

e.g. If item.grade returns A1 `grade: 'A1'` return true, if item.grade returns value not in acceptedGrades return false.

I used the same statement to search for a property with hasOwnProperty and thats fine just need to look for the value of a property.

Can use lodash library.

Comment: Have you considered using `Array.prototype.includes`? `acceptedGrade.includes(item.grade)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to handle that. I think you're after `find`, `filter`, `includes` or `findIndex`. `every` wouldn't be a good fit here because it's evaluating the whole array to make sure all values satisfy your condition. I think you're just trying to match the grade to an item in the array if I'm understanding correctly.

```js
const acceptedGrades = ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3'];

// Get first match:
console.log(acceptedGrades.find( g => g === 'B2')); // returns 'B2'

// Get All Matches:
console.log(acceptedGrades.filter( g => g === 'B2')); // returns ['B2']

// Get Index of first match:
console.log(acceptedGrades.findIndex( g => g === 'B2' )); // returns 4

// See if array 'includes' the value
console.log(acceptedGrades.includes('B2')); // returns true
```

- [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Thankyou - its includes I was after. Cheer pal

Comment: No problem. Please mark as answer if this solves you question.